# How to save the state of a iPhone Switch and print it out?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I have a switch on my ViewController, and whenever I press the save button, I want to use NSLog to print out if the switch is On/Off.

My question is, What data type saves the state of a switch? And how would I print out that variable with the state?

EDIT:

If it was a DatePicker, it would be

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *pickerDate;
```

I need the Switch version of this. NSSwitch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Before asking a question like this it is best to first look at the documentation for `UISwitch`. There you will notice the property named `on`. See what its data type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISwitch has a BOOL property called "on". Say your switch is called "theSwitch"

```
if(theSwitch.on) {
   NSLog(@"on")
}
else {

   NSLog(@"off")
}
```

Comment: If it was a DatePicker, it would be @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *pickerDate;    I need the Switch version of this.  NSSwitch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: not NSSwitch, you should use UISwitch, please double check if the UISwitch variable is nil or not

Comment: I just tested this, and apart from the fact that the name "switch" is actually reserved (going to change it right now) this works. As Lance says, NSSSwitch is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwitch *aSwitch; 


if(aSwitch == nil)
    NSLog("Oops, switch is nil, you cannot save its state");

NSLog(@"switch is:%@", aSwitch.on? @"on", @"off");
```